# When developing a maven project with intellj idea, the module display is sorted

Tags: intellij-idea

I want to display it on the left in the order of modules in the pom.xml file, as follows：

[image]

I know "sort by type",but this is not what I want:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to order modules in intellij-idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31245847/how-to-order-modules-in-intellij-idea)

Comment: I look forward to your sharing on this issue, and I'm very grateful for it.

Comment: If you follow [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31245847/how-to-order-modules-in-intellij-idea) you'll see a previous answer to this same question.

Comment: @glytching : Thanks to you very much, moudle group can be used, and in future versions, I hope JetBrains can solve module custom sort

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to sort module like this, 
refer to the following link: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206256729-Can-I-sort-modules-according-to-the-maven-pom-xml-

The Project view shows the physical structure of your project on disk, not logical structure according to some 
criteria